# Stop SASS from compiling out trailing spaces in CSS

Tags: css, sass, web-compiler

I am trying to target IE 8 & 9 via a browser specific CSS hack as demonstrated [here](http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt).  However, I am using SASS, (in particular, the WebCompiler Visual Studio extension), and it compiles out the trailing spaces before the semicolon.
Thus

```
.class{ display: none \ ;}
```

becomes

```
.class { display: none \;}
```

and breaks the hack.  Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Do you need to recompile the SASS often? I'd say, take the resulting CSS, replace the spaces manually and use that instead of SASS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a space you can concatenate an empty string.

**SASS:**

```
.class{ display: none \ +'';}
```

**Output:**

```
.class {
  display: none \ ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to target with [conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) in html like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>            <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>            <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]> <html>             <![endif]-->
```

And in CSS:

```
.class {display: block;}
.ie8 .class {display: none;}
.ie9 .class {display: none;}
```

But if you want to maintain a cleaner html and a smaller css, you can use some javascript lib to target specific browsers, something like [DetectJS](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Detect.js) to put browser name and version in html tag as class, generate separeted stylesheets for each browser, than call them in your head:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Just remember, [IE10+ didn't accept conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: While I appreciate this method of doing things, in the environment I am working in, I need to avoid adding extra stylesheets, especially for one line of css.

Comment: So you can use js to add a browser info to the body, then put `.ie8 .class,.ie9 .class {display: none;}` inside your existent stylesheet file.